# MySQL Query: List of Part Numbers, Return Only Part Numbers Not in Database

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I know I should be able to figure this out, but I'm not able to figure out the best solution right now.

I have a large list of manufacturer part numbers, for example; 
MF-43644, MY-4354324, DS465454

I need to write a MySQL query that will search a table and one column ('part_num_manuf') in this table. I need to return a result set of the part numbers that are NOT in the table.

The query I would use to return the part numbers that DO exist would look similar to this...
SELECT id, title, part_num_internal, part_num_manuf 
FROM products 
WHERE part_num_manuf IN ('MF-43644', 'MY-4354324', 'DS465454')

I would appreciate any guidance in how I should proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks e4c5, The original question was assuming the 'part_num_manuf' data was not in a table, just a list of part numbers within an 'IN' clause. However, I do agree with you, it's much better if that data is stored in another table. It makes more sense the way you suggested and is fairly quick to load those part numbers into the table whenever necessary. Thank you for the help and guidance.

Comment: glad to have been of help. All the best with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that your part number list is in a table. If it isn't it should be. That would make life a whole lot easier and particularly give you access to the LEFT JOIN

Assuming the part number table is part_numbers and column is part you would then do

```
SELECT part 
FROM part_number LEFT JOIN products
ON part_num_manuf = part WHERE part_num_manuf IS NULL
```

This returns the part numbers that you know of but don't exist in the products table. Perhaps you wanted it the other way round? No fear

```
SELECT part_num_manuf 
FROM products LEFT JOIN part_numbers
ON part_num_manuf = part WHERE part IS NULL
```